# Python to read file and give stock price

Tags: python, file-io, stock

I am using ystockquote which can be found [here](http://goldb.org/ystockquote.html). Basically I have a file with all my stock symbols and then I use python to pen it and display the price for each stock. Here is my code so far:

```
import ystockquote 

def intro():
    # Here you enter the name of your file
    watchlist = raw_input(">")
    open_watchlist = open(watchlist)

   print "What next"
   next = raw_input(">")

   if next == "view":
        for line in open_watchlist:
             quote = ystockquote.get_price(line)
             print "%s: %s" % (line, quote)

intro()
```

which gives the following error:

```
File "hi.py", line 16, in <module>
    intro()
  File "hi.py", line 13, in intro
    quote = ystockquote.get_price(line)
  File "/Users/Nawaz/plancials_beta/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ystockquote.py", line 67, in get_price
    return _request(symbol, 'l1')
  File "/Users/Nawaz/plancials_beta/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ystockquote.py", line 31, in _request
    resp = urlopen(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 402, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1113, in do_request_
    raise URLError('no host given')
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Any ideas on how I can get it to display the symbol and price? Thanks.

Comment: `print "%s: %s" % (line, quuote)`  You misspelled 'quote'

Comment: Thanks I corrected it, but I still cant get it to work. I get [this error](http://pastebin.com/6YbPrn4x)

Comment: Looks like a bug in ystockquote; does it work if you just import it and do a get_price in the interpreter?

Comment: Yea it works perfect. I'm guessing the error is occurring when trying to use the names from the file to get_price.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just misspelled `quote` on the second-to-last line. :)

But for what it's worth: any time you open a resource like a file, you should make sure to close it once you're done. The best way to make sure that this is done by using the `with open` syntax, like this:

```
def intro():
    watchlist = raw_input(">")
    with open(watchlist) as wl:
        print "What next"
        next = raw_input(">")

        if next == "view":
            for line in wl:
                quote = ystockquote.get_price(line)
                print "%s: %s" % (line, quote)

intro()
```

Anything indented further than the `with open ...` line is done with the file currently open. After you're out of that section of the code, the file is automatically closed.

Comment: Thanks I must have mistyped. However, when i corrected it I get [this error](http://pastebin.com/6YbPrn4x)